# Git is merging commits over and over

Tags: git, git-merge

I have a Git repository with two branches: `master` and `Release/v1.0`. On `master` there's a branch policy that I cannot directly push to it, I can just contribute through Pull Requests.

Now, I'm fixing a bug on Release/v1.0 and want to merge it to master.
Therefore I do the following:

```
// create a new branch from master where I merge the changes from Release/v1.0
git checkout -b merge-to-master

// start the merge
git merge origin/Release/v1.0

// merge gets committed automatically, so I just need to push (to upstream if the branch doesn't exist remotely)
git push
```

Now I'm making a Pull Request from `merge-to-master` to `master`. Once the PR is completed, I have all changes in `master`.

The merge works as expected. However, When I start the merge once more, I would expect that those commits do not show up again, because they have already been merged. But the commits are showing up again and again in the merge view.

I assume that the merge info is not written correctly?
Now my question: Am I doing something wrong? How do I avoid the same commits to show up over and over?

@UPDATE:

also, when I want to delete a local branch (`git branch -d v1.0/212760-wrong-status` - which is a feature branch), it tells me:

```
error: The branch 'v1.0/212760-wrong-status' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D v1.0/212760-wrong-status'.
```

But, I already made a PR to Release/v1.0 (and completed it), so I would consider it as fully merged. But why is Git having a different opinion? :)

Comment: Do you pull `master` once the PR has been merged? Otherwise your local repository does not know that `master` now has this PR in.

Comment: `However, When I start the merge once more` ... what does this mean?  Are you reusing the same feature branch over and over?

Comment: Yes, I pull master after the PR. But when I then execute `git log --graph ..Release/v1.0`, it shows me the same (already merged) commits

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It's more a release branch I'm using over and over, because the Release must always be deployable. The feature branches get deleted after the PR is completed.

Comment: @Quentin That could be an explanation, but I have to assume that the OP would be pulling `master` at least occasionally before creating new branches to use.

Comment: That's correct, I'm pulling regularly, so that's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think*, but cannot be sure from the information provided, that this is the key:

> I can [only] contribute through Pull Requests

When you deliver a pull request *to* someone else, you are *asking them* to take some action.  We need to know who the *them* is.  Who *are* they?  Let's find out what, precisely, they are doing!

Let's start with this:

> `v1.0/212760-wrong-status`

I think this means you have done:

```
git checkout -b v1.0/212760-wrong-status v1.0
```

or equivalent in your own repository, and then made a commit or two here to fix a bug.  You then do the:

```
git checkout -b merge-to-master master
git merge origin/Release/v1.0
git push
```

steps.  (It will help a great deal if you draw out the actual steps and actual commit hash IDs and branch names involved here, so that everything is concrete with actual hash IDs.)  Note that `git push` will push the actual commits to some other repository, such as the one you call `origin` or the (presumably different / separate) one you call `upstream`; each push will ask that *other* Git to set some branch name(s) to point to specific commits.

---

At this point, let's also give everyone names so that we know who is taking which action.  I will call you Dave and talk about Dave's commits, which have the specific hash IDs you can see in your repository or repositories (run `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` to see the abbreviated hash IDs and the graph).  I don't have a name for the person operating the upstream repository; let's call her Ursula, which starts with U for Upstream.

Furthermore, these days, "pull request" usually implies a hosting service like GitHub or Bitbucket.  GitHub in particular offers a clicky button, "merge pull request", with a pulldown menu attached to it.  Clicking on the pulldown menu rather than the "merge pull request" button offers three options, which change the action of the clicky button:

- Merge.  This is a straight merge: Ursula will add to Ursula's (upstream) repository, one or more commit made by Dave from Dave's web-hosted repository copy.  Dave's commit(s) will have the hash IDs of Dave's commits, because they *are* Dave's commits.  Ursula will create one new commit with one new, unique hash ID.
- Rebase and merge.  This makes *copies* of Dave's commits.  Ursula will add these copies to Ursula's repository, after which Dave's commits are essentially dead—Dave should replace them with Ursula's copies.
- Squash and merge.  This makes one single new commit, belonging exclusively to Ursula, that makes the same *changes* as Dave's *N* commits (however large *N* is, even if it's just 1).  If *N* = 1 this is remarkably similar to "rebase and merge", though the default commit log message is different.  In either case, Ursula's new single commit obviates all of Dave's original commits, just as with the rebase-and-merge mode.

Once Ursula has finished, you (Dave) can `git fetch` her commit(s)—there's always at least one of hers—from the address you spell using the word `upstream`.  If hers is a true merge, she will have merged the commit you made (I believe) on `v1.0/212760-wrong-status`.  That is, that *exact commit*, with its same hash ID, is now present in Ursula's repository.  Her merge into her `master` has a *different* hash ID from your merge into *your* master, but it does use your original commit.

If you then, in your own repository on your computer (not your `origin` on GitHub or whatever), check out your `master` and fast-forward it to her merge commit (now showing, with `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph`, on your `upstream/master`) and then run:

```
git branch -d v1.0/212760-wrong-status
```

your Git will see that the commit that is the tip of your `v1.0/212760-wrong-status` *is* merged to your current branch `master`.  That is, by looking at Ursula's merge commit's second parent, your Git can trace a direct line from your `master` to that particular commit.  So that commit is contained in `master`, and Git will be happy to delete the *name* `v1.0/212760-wrong-status` from your local repository.

Since this *isn't* the case, we can conclude that Ursula must have used the "rebase and merge" or "squash and merge" mode of the clicky button to make a *copy* of your commit.  If the copy is good enough—if you are happy with the way Ursula copied your commit—you can safely forcibly delete your branch name, losing your original commit (eventually forever though your reflogs will probably retain it for another 30 days or so, if you change your mind).

In other words, if Ursula has *copied* your commit to a new and supposedly improved commit that obviates your original commit, is is now up to you—Dave—to decide whether Dave's original commit should be discarded in favor of this new copy.  That's what your Git is telling you.

If you *don't* discard your own commit like this, your *next* pull request could—depending on how you build it up—*re-introduce* this commit.  Whether it will depends, as usual, on the actual commit graph.  The commit graph—the one that `git log --graph` draws—is what matters.  You provide actual commits, which come with actual graph segments, through your pull requests.  **If they take your actual commits, your graph segments get added, and now you and they share graphs.**  But if they *don't* take your commits, they'll add some *other* commits with different graph segments.  Your Git will add *their* commits to *your* graph, giving you an ever-bigger graph with lots of copies of commits.  It's up to you do decide how you wish to deal with that.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your detailed answer! I think I got your point and I assume this is also the reason why it's not working as expected. So let's clear things up: We're working here in a team, where everyone can only contribute to master via PRs (they have to be reviewed by a team member). We're doing them with VSTS. There's just the option to create a "Pull Request", so no selection between merge, rebase and merge and so on. And I think this is exactly the explanation for my behaviour: VSTS creates a Pull Request as an own commit, so it has a different hash and git has no chance to see ...

Comment: ... wether the commit has already been merged or not. I formerly worked with SVN, and they work with specific merge infos (so not by comparing hashes). So, I assume that the merge-commit has another hash then the original commit. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: After a detailed analysis in VSTS I found out that, in the branch policies there's an option to select the desired merge strategy. So far *Squash Merge* was selected. However, the correct selection to avoid this problem is **No-fast-forward merge**. I tested it and it works like expected. Thanks a lot for your help! :)

Comment: OK, just for future reference the Visual Studios Team Server thing would be a good point to include in future questions. :-) I avoid Windows as much as possible and don't know any of the details of VSTS setup but it sounds similar to GitHub, just even more opaque. (Not that Git itself is all that transparent...)

Comment: Yes, you're totally right on that :) VSTS is quite complex, but you can do a lot with it. Have also been avoiding Microsoft so far, but slowly getting used to it :D