# Why Git is not able to do a "Fast forward" between two remotes?

Tags: git, github

Let say I've this scenario, on two `GitHub` remotes:

```
upstream    A   B   C   D
myremote    A   B   C   D   E
```

I've forked `upstream` at the beginning, and keep updated `myremote` (fetch/merge) during the time. Until I've made myself a new `commit E` on `myremote`.

Working on local repo, when I merge branches with a similar situations of commits (i.e. new commit on a new branch, no new ones in the master), it will result in a simple `Fast forward` when I merge to the destination branch. So the destination branch will just move the `HEAD` pointer.

Working on remotes it seems different. If I do a `Pull request` to `upstream`, it will add two commits on `upstream`: `E` and `F` (which is `Merge pull request #1 from user/myremote`).

So it ends up with this:

```
upstream    A   B   C   D   E   F
```

F basically is a copy of E here, regarding the "content" of data changed in the files.

Why it create `F` when a `Fast forward` to `E` could be sufficient? `F` is just the same commit of `E`, it only gots two different "parents": the new one `E` and the previous one `D`.

It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @HRK44: nope its a different question! Please remove the flag "possible duplicate"

Comment: Keep in mind that pull requests are not a standard Git feature, that's custom-built on top of Git. Whichever server you're using is either limited to the equivalent of `git merge --no-ff`, or configured to it. If it's limited to it, the question should be addressed to whoever designed the server software. If it's configured to it, the question should be addressed to whoever configured it as such. I'm not seeing much here that's answerable in the context of just Git itself.

Comment: @hvd: clear! I've added the server I'm using! If you place this answer (and maybe some further details :P) I think you will get the accepted answer!

Comment: Oh, I posted it as a comment because I don't think it answers your question: it doesn't answer why Github uses `--no-ff`. [It's documented](https://help.github.com/articles/merging-a-pull-request/) that `--no-ff` will be used unless squashing or rebasing, but it's not explained there. I do not know if Github explains their decision anywhere else.

Comment: @hvd: not sure why this is not considered a standard Git feature, since its based and optimized for this kind of stuff: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control "Furthermore, many of these systems deal pretty well with having several remote repositories they can work with, so you can collaborate with different groups of people in different ways simultaneously within the same project."

Comment: @markzzz - I think we should be more clear here: pull requests are not a git feature, standard or otherwise. They are a feature of hosting software like github.  More generally, git has no features concerned with the relationship between remotes.  git is focused on the local repo, with a few means to interact with individual remotes.  As your cited document notes, you can *have* multiple remotes; yet git isn't too interested in the relationships between those remotes.  If it were, it wouldn't be as flexible in how you work with remotes.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but see my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/q/49649073/1256452

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: uhm? It seems a Git feature sync between remotes https://git-scm.com/docs/git-request-pull - why it should be different from sync between (your) local and remote?

Comment: @markzzz - In what way does printing a document describing a proposed pull that you'd like someone to manually run represent a feature that syncs between remotes?  (Answer: it doesn't.)  It's different from sync between (your) local and remote because in a sync between (your) local and remote one of the repos is local.  This is not a debate, it's a fact.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: I meant, the way git will manage the push of commits from `local to remote A` will be the same as pushing commits from `remote A to remote B`. It just differs as source/destination, but the git engine will do the same (I guess). Its all commits and branches after all.

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: I think you misunderstood what I mean with "remotes sync". I don't talk about an auto-sync between remotes. But to manually sync between remotes, as you manually sync between local and remote: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches - since there's request-pull call, I would call it a feature defined by standard, isn't?

Comment: @markzzz - One of the repos involved in a git command is always the local.  Anything else is not defined by git.  End.  Of.  Story

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger: I could agree. I just ask where this is written in the documentation, and why (if that's true) there's command like `request-pull`, which indeed don't involve any local repo at all!